# Tensorflow, Training is nor working

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to implement CNN with MNIST data and I cannot figure out what the problem of this CNN is. Training is not working forever.

In TensorBoard, loss value obtained by cross entropy error is continuously above 20. And validation accuracy is always 0.0868. training accuracy of mini batch(=100) is less than 0.1. It doesn't go up.

I don't know what do I need to do. Here is the code. Can you tell me what is the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
class ConvNetv2(object):

def __init__(self):       

    learning_rate = 0.1
    training_epochs = 10
    batch_size = 100
    display_step = 10
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

    with tf.Graph().as_default():            
        sess = tf.Session()
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
        t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
        self.keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        keep_prob = self.keep_prob
        output = self.inference(x, keep_prob)
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
        cost = self.loss(output, t)
        train_op = self.training(cost, global_step, learning_rate)
        eval_op = self.evaluate(output, t)
        summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
        saver = tf.train.Saver()

        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("board/sample", graph_def=sess.graph_def)
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init_op)

        for epoch in range(training_epochs):
            total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
            avg_cost = 0
            for i in range(500):
                batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                feed_dict = {x : batch_x, t : batch_y, keep_prob : 1.0}
                sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
                accuracy = sess.run(eval_op, feed_dict= feed_dict)
                minibatch_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict=feed_dict)
                avg_cost += minibatch_cost/total_batch
                if i%display_step==0:
                    print('step', i, 'training accuracy', accuracy)
                    accuracy = sess.run(eval_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
                    print(accuracy)
                    val_feed_dict = {x : mnist.validation.images, t : mnist.validation.labels, keep_prob : 1.0}
                    accuracy = sess.run(eval_op, feed_dict=val_feed_dict)
                    summary_str = sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
                    summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, sess.run(global_step))
                    saver.save(sess, "logistic_logs/model-checkpoint", global_step=global_step)
                    print("Validation Accuracy:", (accuracy))

            #if i%display_step==0 :


    print("Optimization Finished!")


    batch_size = 50
    batch_num = int(mnist.test._num_examples / batch_size)
    test_accuracy = 0

    for i in range(batch_num):
        batch = mnist.test.next_batch(batch_size)
        test_accuracy += sess.run(eval_op, feed_dict={x:batch[0], t:batch[1], keep_prob : 1.0})        
    test_accuracy /= batch_num
    print("test accuracy %g"%test_accuracy)         sess.close()        

def conv2d(self, input, weight_shape, bias_shape):
    weightX = weight_shape[0]*weight_shape[1]*weight_shape[2]         
    weight_init = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=(2.0/weightX)**0.5) 
    W = tf.get_variable("W", weight_shape, initializer=weight_init)
    bias_init = tf.constant_initializer(value = 0)
    b = tf.get_variable("b", bias_shape, initializer=bias_init)
    conv_out = tf.nn.conv2d(input, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv_out, b))

def max_pool(self, input, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(input, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1], padding='SAME')

def inference(self, x, keep_prob):
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
    with tf.variable_scope("conv_1"):
        conv_1 = self.conv2d(x, [5, 5, 1, 32], [32]) 
        pool_1 = self.max_pool(conv_1)

    with tf.variable_scope("conv_2"):
        conv_2 = self.conv2d(pool_1, [5, 5, 32, 64], [64])
        pool_2 = self.max_pool(conv_2)

    with tf.variable_scope("fc"):
        pool_2_flat = tf.reshape(pool_2, [-1, 7*7*64]) 
        fc_1 = self.layer(pool_2_flat, [7*7*64, 1024], [1024])
        fc_1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(fc_1, keep_prob)

    with tf.variable_scope("output"):
        output = self.lastlayer(fc_1_drop, [1024, 10], [10])

    return output

def layer(self, input, weight_shape, bias_shape):
    weight_stddev = (2.0/weight_shape[0])**0.5
    w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=weight_stddev)
    bias_init = tf.constant_initializer(value=0)
    W = tf.get_variable("W", weight_shape, initializer=w_init)
    b = tf.get_variable("b", bias_shape, initializer=bias_init)
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, W)+b)  

def lastlayer(self, input, weight_shape, bias_shape):
    weight_stddev = (2.0/weight_shape[0])**0.5
    w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=weight_stddev)
    bias_init = tf.constant_initializer(value=0)
    W = tf.get_variable("W", weight_shape, initializer=w_init)
    b = tf.get_variable("b", bias_shape, initializer=bias_init)
    return tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(input, W)+b)        

def loss(self, output, t):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(t*tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(output, 1e-10, 1.0)), reduction_indices=[1]))
    return loss

def evaluate(self, output, t):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output, 1), tf.argmax(t, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    return accuracy

def training(self, cost, global_step, learning_rate):
    tf.summary.scalar("cost", cost)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)

    return train_op
```

Comment: Please give us more information about your problem. What does your input data look like? What errors or undesired outcomes do you get?

Comment: @divibisan I used MNIST data(60000 * 728) and randomly select 100 data in 1 epoch. As a result, any accuracy didn't go up. Every step, training and validation accuracy is less than 0.1.